# Is there a touch mouse which uses tap to click?

Tags: windows, mouse, hardware-rec

Is there a mouse that supports tap to click, i.e. generate left and right clicks without mechanically pressing a button?

I've tried the Microsoft Touch Mouse, while the extra features for making windows jump up and down work by touch, left and right click don't.

Comment: This SE proposal might interest you: [Hardware Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations?referrer=pkyzvJvq0mtg1JcHSmnJDQ2).

Comment: -> [Does a tap to click mouse exist](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40)

Answer (score 1):

This question is very close to being worded like a shopping or buying recommendation. Nonetheless, I felt it was more of a functional question rather than asking which one to buy. SO, here is what I found.

[Logitech](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice) has a series of touch mice which appear to support left and right tapping to make selections as you described (determined by watching the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hngsYZpk3_A)).

[image]

Comment: My mention of the Microsoft Touch Mouse was _not_ a recommendation - precisely the reverse in fact. It's hard to tell from the video of the Logitech mouse, but after watching the relevant section a dozen or so times my best guess would be that the user is pressing mechanical buttons; Michele Sganga's comment appears to confirm this; am I missing something?

Comment: Not a recommendation from you, rather asking what touch mouse to buy. Don't be surprised if this question gets closed. Feel free to reword the question to avoid it. 

Hmm, I though the video looked like they were tapping it. Guess you will need to contact them, or look at the product at a store.

Comment: Ah, the moderation here is no better than on the other stack exchange sites, understood. Thanks anyway!

Comment: +1. But the video is not accessible anymore :( Also https://www.gadgetreview.com/logitech-ultrathin-touch-mouse-t630-review says that clicking can't be replaced with touching.